# How to define a between variable is random effect in Anova in R?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, experiment-design, split-plot

I am using 'Anova' function in 'car' package to analyze plot - split experimental data.

I have 1 between group, and 2 within group variables, so it is SPFp.qr analysis.

The problem is, the between group variable is random effect, and 2 within group variables are fixed effects. But it seems to me that, R understand all of them are fixed effects.

How can I tell R that the between group variable is random effect?

**Update**

Below are Anova code, and my data:

```
dfW1         <- reshape(df, v.names="score", timevar="WTH1", idvar=c("id","BTW","WTH2"),
                        direction = "wide")
dfSPFp.qrW   <- reshape(dfW1, v.names=c("score.0", "score.1"), timevar="WTH2", 
                        idvar=c("id", "BTW"), direction="wide")
fitSPFp.qr   <- lm(cbind(score.0.0, score.1.0, score.0.1, score.1.1) ~ BTW, 
                   data=dfSPFp.qrW)
inSPFp.qr    <- expand.grid(WTH1=gl(2, 1, labels=c("0","1")), 
                            WTH2=gl(2, 1, labels=c("0","1")) )
AnovaSPFp.qr <- Anova(fitSPFp.qr, idata=inSPFp.qr, idesign=~WTH1*WTH2)
print(summary(AnovaSPFp.qr, multivariate=FALSE, univariate=TRUE))
```

And the result:

```
Univariate Type II Repeated-Measures ANOVA Assuming Sphericity

                   SS num Df Error SS den Df       F    Pr(>F)      
(Intercept)    0.0000      1   32.691     25  0.0000   1.00000     
BTW           15.4270      4   32.691     25  2.9494   0.03991 *  
WTH1          13.0875      1   14.809     25 22.0943 8.099e-05 ***
BTW:WTH1       5.0237      4   14.809     25  2.1203   0.10815    
WTH2          11.1769      1    9.657     25 28.9338 1.402e-05 ***
BTW:WTH2       1.4321      4    9.657     25  0.9268   0.46420    
WTH1:WTH2      7.0250      1    7.959     25 22.0653 8.164e-05 ***
BTW:WTH1:WTH2  1.7118      4    7.959     25  1.3442   0.28142
```

My data:

```
str (df)
'data.frame': 120 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id     : Factor w/ 30 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ... 
 $ BTW    : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ WTH1   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ WTH2   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ score: num  -1.06 -0.678 1.194 1.94 -1.06 ...

df <- read.table(text="id BTW WTH1 WTH2       score
                1   1    0    0 -1.16055841
                1   1    0    1 -0.78485342
                1   1    1    0  1.05951654
                1   1    1    1  1.79384902
                7   2    0    0 -0.44330343
                7   2    0    1  1.87923652
                7   2    1    0 -0.44330343
                7   2    1    1 -0.42622593
               13   3    0    0 -1.16055841
               13   3    0    1 -0.22129593
               13   3    1    0  0.29102906
               13   3    1    1  0.71796654
               19   4    0    0 -0.40914843
               19   4    0    1  0.49595905
               19   4    1    0  1.69138402
               19   4    1    1  0.35933905
               25   5    0    0 -0.30668343
               25   5    0    1 -0.40914843
               25   5    1    0  1.84508152
               25   5    1    1 -0.13590843
                2   1    0    0 -1.16055841
                2   1    0    1 -1.10932591
                2   1    1    0 -0.93855091
                2   1    1    1 -1.02393841
                8   2    0    0 -1.01629043
                8   2    0    1  0.11668190
                8   2    1    0  0.26631975
                8   2    1    1  0.82211750
               14   3    0    0 -0.18259381
               14   3    0    1  0.95037852
               14   3    1    0  1.20690056
               14   3    1    1  1.31378474
               20   4    0    0 -0.54600003
               20   4    0    1  1.50617627
               20   4    1    0 -1.03766727
               20   4    1    1  1.67719096
               26   5    0    0 -0.73839156
               26   5    0    1 -0.67426105
               26   5    1    0 -1.16592829
               26   5    1    1  0.35182710
                3   1    0    0 -1.27281247
                3   1    0    1  1.50617627
                3   1    1    0  1.10001638
                3   1    1    1 -0.20397065
                9   2    0    0 -1.10179778
                9   2    0    1 -0.97353676
                9   2    1    0 -0.82389890
                9   2    1    1 -1.08042094
               15   3    0    0 -1.37219594
               15   3    0    1 -0.55904279
               15   3    1    0 -0.28257072
               15   3    1    1  0.12400586
               21   4    0    0 -0.38014910
               21   4    0    1  0.25411036
               21   4    1    0 -0.07115090
               21   4    1    1 -0.05488784
               27   5    0    0 -0.67288423
               27   5    0    1 -0.21751847
               27   5    1    0 -0.64035811
               27   5    1    1  0.35168874
                4   1    0    0 -1.22582837
                4   1    0    1  0.15653198
                4   1    1    0  0.62816081
                4   1    1    1 -0.68914730
               10   2    0    0 -1.06319774
               10   2    0    1 -0.39641216
               10   2    1    0 -0.02236171
               10   2    1    1  0.23784730
               16   3    0    0 -0.64035811
               16   3    0    1  1.18110495
               16   3    1    0  2.14062567
               16   3    1    1  3.21398783
               22   4    0    0 -0.59035895
               22   4    0    1  0.04005773
               22   4    1    0 -0.29091103
               22   4    1    1 -0.22786936
               28   5    0    0 -1.34685897
               28   5    0    1 -1.25229646
               28   5    1    0 -1.28381730
               28   5    1    1 -1.03165063
                5   1    0    0 -1.37837980
                5   1    0    1  0.40254732
                5   1    1    0  0.48134940
                5   1    1    1  0.81231816
               11   2    0    0 -1.40990063
               11   2    0    1  1.04872441
               11   2    1    0 -0.27515061
               11   2    1    1  0.35526607
               17   3    0    0 -0.35395270
               17   3    0    1  1.41121400
               17   3    1    0  2.18347443
               17   3    1    1  1.89978693
               23   4    0    0 -0.32243186
               23   4    0    1  0.40254732
               23   4    1    0  0.63895357
               23   4    1    1  0.08733898
               29   5    0    0 -0.76451809
               29   5    0    1  0.15770687
               29   5    1    0 -0.01521031
               29   5    1    1 -0.26497957
                6   1    0    0 -1.30248265
                6   1    0    1  0.50354123
                6   1    1    0 -1.20641755
                6   1    1    1 -1.34090869
               12   2    0    0 -1.53303889
               12   2    0    1 -0.09206239
               12   2    1    0 -0.53396185
               12   2    1    1  0.19613291
               18   3    0    0 -1.53303889
               18   3    0    1  0.33062405
               18   3    1    0  1.42576620
               18   3    1    1  1.00307976
               24   4    0    0 -0.47632279
               24   4    0    1  0.71488446
               24   4    1    0  1.71396150
               24   4    1    1  2.34799116
               30   5    0    0 -0.45710977
               30   5    0    1  0.13849385
               30   5    1    0  0.36905009
               30   5    1    1  0.61881936", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Use `lme4`'s `lmer` function.

Comment: lme4 function is great, but I could not interpret the result of lme4. Could you help?

Answer (score 2):

( By the way, your question is difficult to read, the names in your code uses the naming codes by Roger Kirk, see his [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1412974453), you should have explained that! )

The way to analyze split-plot experiments now is mixed models. I will show an analyzes using R and the package `lme4`. The description of your experiment in the question text is not entirely clear, but with help from the structure of your data sets it seems the plots each split in 4 are identified by variable `id`. So, following your code:

```
mydf <- within(df, { BTW <- as.factor(BTW);
    WTH1 <- as.factor(WTH1);
    WTH2 <- as.factor(WTH2);
    id <- as.factor(id)} )
mod0 <- lme4::lmer(score ~ WTH1 * WTH2 + (1 | BTW / id ), data=mydf)
```

with results

```
summary(mod0)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: score ~ WTH1 * WTH2 + (1 | BTW/id)
   Data: mydf

REML criterion at convergence: 288.6

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.39482 -0.67228 -0.03024  0.56765  2.55310 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id:BTW   (Intercept) 0.2103   0.4585  
 BTW      (Intercept) 0.1062   0.3259  
 Residual             0.4666   0.6831  
Number of obs: 120, groups:  id:BTW, 30; BTW, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  -0.8774     0.2093  -4.192
WTH11         1.1444     0.1764   6.489
WTH21         1.0943     0.1764   6.205
WTH11:WTH21  -0.9678     0.2494  -3.880

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) WTH11  WTH21 
WTH11       -0.421              
WTH21       -0.421  0.500       
WTH11:WTH21  0.298 -0.707 -0.707
> confint(mod0)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
                 2.5 %     97.5 %
.sig01       0.2784776  0.7004256
.sig02       0.0000000  0.7458222
.sigma       0.5842574  0.7830592
(Intercept) -1.3023116 -0.4524686
WTH11        0.8008774  1.4879249
WTH21        0.7507645  1.4378120
WTH11:WTH21 -1.4536343 -0.4820023
```