# How to study split-plot design

Tags: mixed-model, experiment-design, split-plot

Is it possible to study a split-plot design with a mixed model? I've seen a related [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19818/split-split-plot-design-and-lme) so I guess it is doable in general. Is there any certain function or procedure I can use? Or can you give an advice in general?

Comment: See one example in my recent answer here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178619/how-to-define-a-between-variable-is-random-effect-in-anova-in-r/428638#428638    Feel free to ask in comments there for clarifications!

Comment: great, thank you! I will dive into the topic and will probably come back soon.